# The Image is not getting displayed at the background of column in table in master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, background-image

```
   <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>






    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 50px;
            height: 323px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 650px;
            height: 323px;
        }
    </style>      

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:30px; height:20px;">
        <img src="Image/Blue%20hills.jpg" 
            style="height: 83px; width: 734px;" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="background-color:Black; background-image:url('~/Images/Bluehills.jpg');"  class="style1">

    </td>
    <td class="style2">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>
    reserved &copy; softech infoways
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am adding background image but in code it is not displayed in this post dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<td style="background-color:Black; background-image:url('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/Bluehills.jpg") %>');"  class="style1">
</td>
```

and make sure that the `/Images/Bluehills.jpg` image actually exists (I see that in your `<img>` tag you are using a different image name, one with a space in its name and located in the `Image` folder instead of `Images`).

Also make sure that you define some height and width of the `<td>` or the image might not display:

```
<td style="background-color:Black; width: 100px; height: 100px; background:url('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/Bluehills.jpg") %>') no-repeat;" class="style1">
</td>
```

I would also strongly recommend you using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect what images are loaded and for those that are not loaded see the reason. It is an excellent tool and a must-have for every web developer.

Comment: @jagdeep, and what does FireBug say about it? What's the reason?

Comment: @jagdeep, I also noticed that your `<td>` is empty meaning that there is not place for the image to display. Try defining it a fixed `width` and `height` or put some contents inside.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov: I have added some text but only text is displayed not background image.     Thanks for kind replies.

Comment: @jagdeep, when I tested this code it worked for me. Try inspecting the DOM with FireBug. It will show you exactly what styles are being applied for this `<td>`. I don't know how can I help any more.

Answer (score 0):

Found a strange but got the image to display

Here is solution i used it without tilde sign and it work don't know why please if u know help me to understand

Small line Code is

```
<td style="background-image:url(Image/Bluehills.jpg);"  class="style1">
oiyhoyhobhobjho
jgkifjklhjljh
hghdoyjofjohjypt
dhgijrlyjhoftjpohktpu

</td>
```

By using this image get displayed